# PHP: Execute another PHP file without including it

Tags: php

When a user uploads an image on my website, I want to automatically create a smaller thumbnail for it and save it - without displaying the thumbnail to the user after the upload is done.
I'm doing the thumbnail creation in a PHP file with an Image-Header and I'm currently executing this PHP file by including it in the HTML response after the upload is done:

```
<img src="createthumb.php?id=ID_FOR_JUST_UPLOADED_FILE" style="display: none">
```

That seems to be a very hacky way for me to execute the createthumb.php file and it also seems to fail sometimes - for example when the user leaves the page before he retrieves the HMTL response after the upload; or maybe because some browsers don't load images with `display: none`.

Either way, I'm trying to find a PHP function which executes the createthumb.php (asynchrounously) without including it in the response to the user.
`include` and `require` obviously don't work.

Comment: When one needs to do that asynchronously - they use queues. Have a look on gearman or rabbitmq.

Comment: Is there no way with standard PHP functions? I don't really want to install/include extra libraries for that...

Comment: PHP runs only while it processes a request. If that does not fit your scenario (and it does not) - you need to use something external.

Comment: Well then forget about the asynchrony; I also wouldn't really mind if it was done during the process of the main file. cURL maybe? (I already have that installed for cross-website request. Never thought about using it for inter-site requests)

Comment: If it's not asynchronous and is in fact synchronous - use `include`.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I can't include files with an Image-Header; but then I noticed that the file doesn't even have such a header because it's not displaying the image... Well, my fault :) Should have thought of that already. Thanks then

Comment: how are you handling the original image upload ?  I would modify that process to create the thumbnail on upload

Comment: Why not use cURL to request the url that is represented in the img tags?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want AJAX.

The basic concept is that your client side script (maybe JavaScript) can generate a request for your server script (php in this case). The server script receives the request and processes it, then sends an asynchronous return message to your client script.

For your case, you could have a JavaScript function triggered on any file upload. The function sends your request to the php script and creates your thumbnail in the background without disturbing the user's current view. Take a look at the W3Schools tutorial.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Ajax is not what I want for that. That'd be the same thing as the include in an `img`-tag. If the user uploads something and leaves the page before he receives the HTML response, the Ajax request is never sent.